# How to list all the packages with dependencies within a package group in RedHat / CentOS 8

Tags: centos, redhat, yum, dnf

If I run the command

`dnf groupinstall --downloadonly core`

then it will

- list all the packages which belongs to the package group `core`,
- resolve their dependencies and
- download the rpms locally.

What I want is not to download but only list.  Is there any easy way to resolve all dependencies related to all packages pertaining to a particular package group?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about the strait way to get the list. But you can download them w/o actually store them in your system:

```
dnf groupinstall --downloadonly --downloaddir=/dev/null core
```

This command will list all the packages to be downloaded so grab the output strip unnecessary lines and voila.

If this do not work you can try combination of:

```
yum deplist <package>
```

and

```
yum groupinfo core
```

You can get the list of packages with `groupinfo` and loop and get the dependencies via `deplist`

Comment: Could have been a real solution but unfortunately not..  ```$ dnf groupinstall --downloadonly --downloaddir=/dev/null core
[Errno 17] File exists: '/dev/null'
$```

Comment: `yum groupinfo` will give the packages a particular group has not the dependencies.  On the other hand `yum deplist` does not take group as parameter.  Looks like I need to loop through.

Comment: @BTRNaidu, right, I give you the base options, you can get the list of packages with `groupinfo` and loop and get the dependencies via `deplist`

Comment: this is not what I wanted.  But your first answer gave me a clue..  Thanks